# React google map getBounds

Tags: reactjs, react-google-maps

I use react-google-maps library and when I get the boundaries through function getBounds. I got the object which looks like this

```
_.Kc {f: Jc, b: Fc}
 b:Fc {b: -69.44550556640627, f: -69.37409443359377}
 f:Jc {b: 5.843139027557267, f: 5.958055017316458}
 __proto__:Object
```

And I need the Bottom left boundary (lat, lng) and Top right boundary (lat, lng).
Could you show me what is the number b and f?
which one is bottom left boundary lat, bottom left boundary lng, top right boundary lat, top right boundary lng. I cant find any documentation

Comment: Really cannot find the answer. Sb helps plz. Thank you in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`Map.getBounds` method](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/map#Map.getBounds) returns [`LatLngBounds` value](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/coordinates#LatLngBounds) which

> represents a rectangle in geographical coordinates, including one
>   that crosses the 180 degrees longitudinal meridian

Use

- [`getNorthEast` method](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/coordinates#LatLngBounds.getNorthEast) to get north-east corner of this bounds (top right boundary lat and lng)
- [`getSouthWest` method](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/coordinates#LatLngBounds.getSouthWest) to get south-west corner of this bounds (bottom left boundary lat and lng)

Example:

```
    onMapIdle={() => {
        let ne = this.map.getBounds().getNorthEast();
        let sw = this.map.getBounds().getSouthWest();
        console.log(ne.lat() + ";" + ne.lng());
        console.log(sw.lat() + ";" + sw.lng());
      }}
```

Here is a [demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/30v1268ro6) for your reference